# How do I generate a plot, pause the program until the Figure is closed, then return to the main function

Tags: python, matplotlib

I currently am trying to create a program that will let me digest data quickly. The beginning of the program (not shown) takes in the data and processes it to make it human-readable. The problem I am having involves how to create a main function that the program will keep returning to after a figure is generated and subsequently closed, in order to make it easier to look at many graphs one after another.

**Problem statement**: I want to generate a graph, have it pop up, and have the program pause in the background while the figure is on screen. Then, when it has closed, I want the program to resume, and return to main.

**Current roadblock**: I have tried a number of different ways of creating the figure, but I cannot seem to do both: (a) correctly generate the figure, and (b) have the program resume and return to main, at the same time. I found that a 'try --> finally' method helps me get back to the main function, but now my graphs wont appear and the kernel crashes.

The code is as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class App(cmd.Cmd):

    prompt = 'Plot an Individual Pulse (a) or the entire array of data (b)? Just type a or b please: '

    def do_a(self, arg):
        userchoice= input('Would you like to see (a) Trimmed Data, or (b) another option (which the code is omitted for space)')
        if userchoice == "a":
            try:
                plt.plot(TrimmedVal)
                plt.title("All Trimmed Data (Includes 0's)")
                plt.ylabel("Number of Particles")
                plt.xlabel("Time (s)")
                plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='y', scilimits=(0,0))
                plt.draw()
                while plt.fignum_exists(1):
                    plt.pause
                return 
            finally: App().cmdloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    App().cmdloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

What you ask for is the default in non-interactive mode, i.e. if you run a script or `plt.ioff()` is called in interactive interpreters.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def myfunc():
    plt.plot(..)
    plt.show()

def main()
    myfunc()
    print("we're back in main")

main()
```

Comment: I think I am beginning to understand. The issue is that I should move the plotting to a different function, so when I plot something I can return to main. The way I am doing it now is confined within main, which I guess is my problem. Thank you.